# Using StringBuilder with a computation expression, in F#

Tags: f#, stringbuilder

I have a lot of code using string builders and I am looking for a way to simplify the syntax.

I started to look at this snippet: http://www.fssnip.net/7WR/title/Computation-expression-over-StringBuilder.

First, I am a vague general idea about computation expressions, but I have never written one and this is something I was hoping to understand better by using this snippet.

The snippet can be used very simply:

```
stringBuffer
    {
        "my first string\n"
        "and the second one\n"
        sprintf "hello %s" "thomas"
    }
```

and this all works well, and outputs a string.

The question arises when processing lists.
I have code like:

```
myList |> Map.map (fun _ data -> data.DescribeIntoAString)
```

this will definitely not work because of the map. How can I make this work?

Comment: The output of the ``Map.map`` function is a map. Maybe you want to use e.g. ``Map.toList`` instead to convert the map to a list of strings, and then add them to the string builder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off: from the usage of `Map.map` (as opposed to `List.map`), it appears that your `myList` is actually a map, not a list.

Now, the snippet you linked does offer an example of using a sequence of something inside the computation builder:

```
let bytes2hex (bytes: byte array) : string =
    stringBuffer {
        for b in bytes -> b
    }
```

You could use this facility to iterate over your map. One thing to notice is that when a `Map` is iterated over, the element type is `KeyValuePair<_, _>`, whose values can be accessed via the `.Value` property:

```
stringBuffer {
    for kvp in myList -> kvp.Value.DescribeIntoAString
}
```